# Find $A^n$, if $n$ is Natural number

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, exponentiation

Find eqation for:$\ A^n$ when:

$$A =\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & 1 & 0\\
0 & a & 1\\
0 & 0 & a\end{array} \right)$$

I calculated $\ A^2$ $\ A^3$ and compared entries:

At the end I've got something like:

$$A^n =\left( \begin{array}{cc}
a^n & na^{n-1} & ???\\
0 & a^n & na^{n-1}\\
0 & 0 & a^n\end{array} \right)$$

So I'm struggling with estimating value of the last entry.

From my calculations I've got respectively: $\ 0 $ $\ 1 $ $\ 3a $. How I can find the equation for this sequence?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Matrix_functions

Answer (score 10):

Hint : let $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$. You have $A=aI+B$. Then use the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$$A^2 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a^2 & 2 a & 1 \\
 0 & a^2 & 2 a \\
 0 & 0 & a^2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$A^3 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a^3 & 3 a^2 & 3 a \\
 0 & a^3 & 3 a^2 \\
 0 & 0 & a^3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$A^4 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a^4 & 4 a^3 & 6 a^2 \\
 0 & a^4 & 4 a^3 \\
 0 & 0 & a^4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$A^5 = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a^5 & 5 a^4 & 10 a^3 \\
 0 & a^5 & 5 a^4 \\
 0 & 0 & a^5 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now the sequence in the top right element:

$$1, 3, 6, 10, ...$$

Doesn't remember you about the binomial expansion? :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint1**: Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and diagonalize the matrix

$A = P^{-1}BP$ then $A^n = P^{-1}B^nP$.

Here $B$ is a diagonal matrix so $n$th power of $B$ will be easy to find.

**Hint2:** You can also find nth power of $A$ by using char polynomial.

Comment: The matrix $A$ is not diagonaliable.

Comment: Diagonalize a $3\times3$ matrix with a triple eigenvalue which is not a scalar matrix? How would you do it?